# How to use multiple actions for one click function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple image of gears and I want them to rotate opposite directions when leaving the page when clicking on a button. The action does not have to perform if navigating away from the website, only if clicked on the buttons within the page. here is the code I have:

```
<script>
    $('#blue1').click( function() {
        $('.animated3').addClass("rotateOut");
        $('.animated2').addClass('rotateIn');   
    });
</script>
```

When I click the button I only get the first animation to play and cant get the second one to work and I'm not sure why. any help would be much appreciated.I will be doing this for multiple buttons. Note: There is already a setTimeout function on another element to delay the page unload.

---

The CSS for the above code is:

```
    .location {margin-top:-430px; margin-left: 445px;}

    #tjgears {
        position:absolute;
        left:200px;
        top:-120px;
    }

.animated2 {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.animated3 {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine. Maybe an element with class `animated2` does not exist.

Comment: Yea I'm not seeing a problem with your code there. Could you paste your html for the animated areas?

Comment: By themselves, the classes "rotateOut" and "rotateIn" won't make gears rotate; we need to see more code. Are you using CSS transitions?

Comment: Any chance you already have the 'rotateIn' class applied to the gears when the page first loads?

Comment: I am using css transitions.

 <div id="tjgears" style="z-index:-1;">
<div>
<img class="animated2 rotateOut" src="Images/TGEAR.png" />
</div>
<div>
<img class="location animated3 rotateIn" src="Images/JGEAR.png" />
</div>
</div>

Comment: these gears rotate in and then out on entering page and when changing the page.

Comment: is #blue1 a link or a div?

Comment: <nav>

        <ul id="Navigation">
         <li id="pink1"><p><strong>Home</strong></p></li>
            <li id="blue1"><p><strong>Portfolio</strong></p></li>
            <li id="orange1"><p><strong>Contact</strong></p></li>
            <li id="green1"><p><strong>Mission</strong></p></li>
     </ul>
        </nav>

Comment: #blue1 is an id of a list item

Comment: Please add the CSS to your original question. It's looking like that's the likely source of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, and without seeing the actual CSS, it appears as though the `rotateIn` and `rotateOut` classes (and their associated transitions) may be conflicting as they're not being removed after the click event.

Try the following:

```
$('#blue1').click( function() {
    // Remove any existing transition classes first
    $('.animated2, .animated3').removeClass('rotateIn rotateOut');

    // Add new transition classes to appropriate elements
    $('.animated3').addClass('rotateOut');
    $('.animated2').addClass('rotateIn');   
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Please take a moment to mark the answer as accepted if the solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle which should help you. In my solution I make use of toggleClass for the two animated gears your are looking to rotate. I also use @-webkit-keyframes to create an animation for each class.

I didn't use actual images as I was hoping it would serve its purpose without it. 
http://jsfiddle.net/5qQW9/

THE HTML : (modify to suite)

```
<div id="blue1">
    <div class="animated2">animated2</div>
    <div class="animated3">animated3</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotateOut {
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateIn {
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

.rotateOut {
    -webkit-animation: rotateOut 10s linear infinite;
}

.rotateIn {
    -webkit-animation: rotateIn 10s linear infinite;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#blue1').on('click', function() {
     $('.animated3').toggleClass("rotateOut");
     $('.animated2').toggleClass('rotateIn');   
});
```

So when you click the div, it applies the class for each and on another click removes them. This will create the desired animation effect of one gear rotatiing one way and the other , the opposite direction.